# Create a set of android API objects

Tags: android, set

I need to create a set of android objects (BluetoothDevice objects). Of course, I chose a Set because I don't want any duplicate in my Collection.

My problem is the following : 
When I do a bluetooth discovery in Android I receive twice the same device (for e.g. device WINIE7, with mac 80:22:00:22:00), and the references are not the same, so both of them are added in the Set.

Would it be possible to create a kind of "Comparator" to my Set, which would tell to compare the mac addresses ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `equals` method of your `BluetoothDevice` object to return `true` if the hashes are equal. Also override the `hashCode` method to comply with its specification, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609).

Comment: I don't have any access on BluetoothDevice object. This object comes from Android API...